# I would like the table "rowspan" command to start working. Now is on total ignore

Tags: html

I am trying to make a simple table in html and half way on the project, I run into a problem. I am trying to make 2nd to last row to spread to be double in size and I used `rowspan="2"` and nothing happened. Can you please help me?

Comment: https://codepen.io/vlada_vuckovic/pen/RwbJqMd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rowspan` causes a cell to span multiple rows in a table. If all of the cells in a row have the same rowspan, nothing happens because there is no room in the row for cells from subsequent rows to move into the current row.

If you just want to make a row look taller, you can use CSS to adjust the padding, font size, etc.